# How to find if list instance is available in another list or not?

Tags: python

I have two sets of lists.

```
list A= [(1,6),(3,10),(4,1),(0,5)]
list B = [(0,3),(0,4),(30,1),(4,10)]
```

Now for each item in B, I have to check if its available in list A or not for a threshold of -2 to +2.

So the very first value in B which is (0,3), for that using threshold in each point I have found that `(from -2 to 2, from 1 to 5)` within this rage a list item is available in the list A or not. We can see that the last item value `(0,5)` fulfil this condition. so I can say that item `(0,3)` is in list A.Now I have to put this value in a new list.

According to the process, my new list would be :

```
[(0,3),(0,4),(4,10)]
```

I will be so glad if somebody tells me how to achieve this.

Comment: Why? `(3, 1)` also exists in `listA` within those thresholds (i.e. `(4, 1)`).

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake. i have updated the array. @Selcuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i think you are looking for

```
A= [(1,6),(3,10),(4,1),(0,5)]
B = [(0,3),(0,4),(30,1),(4,10)]

result=[x for x in B if any(x[0]-2<=a[0]<=x[0]+2 and  x[1]-2<=a[1]<=x[1]+2   for a in A)]

print(result)
```

output :

```
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (4, 10)]
```

Comment: np, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

You can use taxi cab geometry:

```
def manhattan(as_, b):
    threshold = 4
    for a in as_:
        p1, p2 = a
        q1, q2 = b
        dist = abs(p1 - q1) + abs(p2 - q2)
        if dist <= threshold:
            return b
        else:
            continue

t = list(filter(lambda i: manhattan(listA, i), listB))

[(0, 3), (0, 4), (4, 10)]
```

Or

```
from operator import truth

t = list(filter(truth, (manhattan(listA, i) for i in listB)))
```